# Fast function objects in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, function, object, functional-programming

I'm writing a program for scientific computing and my foremost interest (after correctness) is speed. Recently I have noticed that I need readable code too. :)

Instead of writing

```
for (int k=0;k!=10;k+=1)
   array[k] = fun(a, k);
```

I'm considering writing

```
class fun_t {
private:
   type a;
public:
   fun_t(type in) : a(in) {};

   type operator() (int k) {
      ...computation...
   }
};
...
fun_t fun(a);
for (int k=0;k!=10;k+=1)
   array[k] = fun(k);
```

Will the function object style be as fast as the first example? Can I expect the same inlinings in both? Is there a better a way? (Note that I'm only presenting the idea here, this is not my actual code.)

Comment: Since C++11, there are anonymous functions (`lambda`) in the language.

Comment: The best way to find out is to profile.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Do you mean I should write two versions of my program? Can't I ask the compiler to verify that inlining is happening?

Comment: @larsmans: Do you know anything of the speed and maturity of the lambda implementation of GCC?

Comment: @Mankka what is the compiler? With GCC you can compile with -S and it stops after generating assembly so you can inspect it and verify if it did the optimizations you were expecting.

Comment: @Mankka: a lambda simply compiles down to a functor (function objects), and a functor is trivial for the compiler to inline. So it should be essentially free (as would the version you outlined in the question). But as always, if performance matters, don't trust random people on the internet, *measure* it in your code

Comment: I can't see these 2 versions being very different. If speed matters use a profiler and it will show up a bottleneck in a completely different place to anywhere you expect. You're calling fun 10 times anyway, so you got 10 function calls vs 11. Of all the performance problems I've ever had with compilers, inlining isn't one of them though.

Comment: I appreciate that this is just an example, but you mention that you want readable code but then you've gone from a two liner - which to me is very readable - to 10 lines, which actually includes (virtually) your original two lines. From a readability perspective, I'd say it's a backward step.

Comment: 10 isn't exactly a lot of calls even if the compiler can't inline it. Is this just an example and it really calls it a million times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expect the same inlinings from a reasonable compiler. The destination of the call to `operator()` is known at compile-time just like the call to `fun(a,k)`.

The difference I see is in the access to `a`. In the case of the function `fun`, you pass *something* as a parameter -- without the declaration of `fun` it's not possible to see whether this is a copy of `a`, a reference to `a`, or some other type constructed from `a`.

In the case of the functor `fun_t`, you copy `a` once to construct the functor. You (nominally) pass a `fun_t*` as `this` to `operator()`, and then `a` is accessed as `this->a`. The extra indirection might well be elided once everything is inlined and the optimizer has finished, but then again it might not. You would have to check specific cases, probably by examining the instructions emitted by the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose the heavy computation is performed inside your function. Compared to that differences between direct function call and member function call should be insignificant.

Comment: Very good point! The computation in the function used to be quite small and fast but now I'm refactoring and rewriting in MPI so I'm not sure how things will turn out. Maybe I good time to step back and look at the big picture.

Comment: Yes, it is only getting called 10 times. The saving you get from inlining is the stack wind/unwind, jump and parameter pushing on each call. That is a reasonably fast operation though and doing it 10 times isn't likely to slow down your program in any noticeable way.

Answer (score 1):

There may be small optimisations you can make by changing the loop construct, but the main purpose of these is not for speed improvement.

If you want speed improvement you need to profile. If `fun(a,k)` in particular is a slow operation and each run is not dependent on the others, you should consider splitting into threads and running each one on its own thread.

There are new APIs coming to operate over collections in parallel rather than series. Exciting times ahead.

Comment: What do you mean, "There are new APIs coming"? C++11 has been here for a year already!

Comment: Just to make it clear: I do agree that profiling is your #1 solution to making code faster. Vectorization and Parallelization are an obvious solution if profiling proves that you want to optimize loops.

Comment: @KlassvanGend coming to actually be implemented on your compiler / in your standard library.